# How do I make the mysql-server and plesk work?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, plesk

Plesk asked for a new licence-key, and I read that restarting via `/etc/init.d/psa stopall` and `/etc/init.d/psa start` helps. I got

```
root@test:~# /etc/init.d/psa stopall
Stopping tomcat service...                                            not installed
Stopping apache service...                                            done
Stopping virusfilter service...                                       not installed
Stopping spamfilter service...                                        not installed
Stopping mailer service...                                            done
Stopping named service...                                             already stopped
Stopping mysql service...                                             done
Stopping sw_cp_server service...                                      done
Stopping sw_engine service...                                         done
root@test:~# /etc/init.d/psa start
Starting sw_engine service... invoke-rc.d: initscript sw-engine, action "status" failed.
                                                                      done
Starting sw_cp_server service... invoke-rc.d: initscript sw-cp-server, action "status" failed.
                                                                      done
Starting mysql service...                                             already started
Starting named service...                                             done
Starting mailer service...                                            done
Starting spamfilter service...                                        not installed
Starting tomcat service...                                            not installed
Starting apache service...                                            done
Starting superserver service...                                       already started
Starting sw_engine service...                                         already started
```

And this is when I could not use any webpage with mysql access anymore as in `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Also, I cannot access plesk anymore, it says `ERROR: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.sessions' doesn't exist (Pdo.php:234)`

How do I make the mysql-server and plesk work?

Comment: This is pure operations related question, sysadmins would be in a lot better position to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it with

plesk repair installation

plesk repair db

Comment: Check this KB article https://kb.plesk.com/en/120686 Maybe it is your case.

Comment: This is what happened: http://pastebin.com/ggxLGRhR Still the same problem. Maybe the key for all of this is to be found in `/etc/init.d/psa stopall` and `/etc/init.d/psa start` as after running this the whole problem started...